# Extracting information from two different databases in Crystal Report

Tags: sql, ms-access, crystal-reports, multiple-databases

I am looking to get information from two different databases: 1 is a SQL database and 2 is an MS Access table. Both sources don't have a unique identifier to link them to each other so what I've tried doing is, I created a MS Access table with a list of codes (around 20) that exist for both sources and linking via this table in Crystal but that didn't work.
I am creating a report to show various transactions groups so the transactions are coming from either SQL DB of a system or MS Access table.

Please note I am not familiar with unions in Crystal but I am in Access.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: SQL is not a database - it is a language that even Access uses. Do you mean SQLServer or MySQL or some other? Simplest approach may be to have Access link to other table (or vice versa) and then CR can just pull from one db. And a quick web search returns articles on how to do UNION in CR. Or with the link in Access, build UNION in Access and CR looks at that query. What does "didn't work" mean - error message, wrong result, nothing happens?

Comment: If each record in each table is an independent transaction, why would you even JOIN these two datasets? Seems UNION is what you need.

Comment: Is CR offering more functionality than what Access reporting can do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's a client data that comes from two different systems, we have ODBC connection to one of them but not the 2nd (i can only extract a report from the 2nd one and import into Access as a table). the data contains transactions on hundreds of accounts. i am creating a report to show all transactions received per specific group (based on specific criteria e.g. type of transaction). Both systems in question have the same client but the accounts are unique and the only way i thought to link them was to create an Access table with a list of client codes that exist for both and then linking in CR.

Comment: also what i meant was that it was a SQL based database....

Comment: Your comments do not clarify. Did not really respond to suggestion/questions. Still did not identify database platforms.